# Sections in the structured sheaf over integral domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

I'm having a trouble in Dummit and Foote's Abstract algebra, section 5 of Chapter 15. For an integral domain $R$ with quotient field $F$, I want to show that for a given open set  $U\subseteq \operatorname{Spec} R$

$$\mathcal O(U) = \{ \frac{a}{b} \in F \mid b \notin P \; \;\text{for all}\; P \in U\}.$$

My attempt was to construct a map from $\{ \frac{a}{b} \in F \mid b \notin P \; \;\text{for all}\; P \in U\}$ to $\mathcal O(U)$. Pick $s \in\mathcal O(U)$. Then $U = Xg_1\cup\cdots\cup Xg_k$. Where $s$ maps $Xg_i$ to $\left( \frac{a_i}{g_i^n}\right)$. Since $R$ is an integral domain, $Xg_ig_j = Xg_i\cap Xg_j \neq \emptyset$ for any pair $(i , j)$. So $\left( \frac{a_i}{g_i^n}\right)= \left( \frac{a_j}{g_j^n}\right)$ in $F$. Let $$f = \sum_{i=0}^ng_i^n$$ Then $a_jg_j^nf = \sum_{i=0}^na_ig_j^{2n}$. So $\left(\frac{a_j}{g_j^n}\right)=\left(\frac{a}{f}\right)$, where $a =  \sum_{i=0}^na_i$

If I could show $f \notin P$ for all $P \in U$ then this map is surjective. But, I can't proceed any further.... Is my attempt completely wrong? Could anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Du you know $\mathcal O(U) = \bigcap_{P \in U} A_P$?

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. However, I don't know that.... . Could you tell me what you mean by Ap ??

Comment: @TetsuHirosawa $A_P$ is the localization of $A$ at the (complement of) the prime ideal $P$.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring#Examples).  Also, I have to ask: why did you format your question so strangely?  You can write text without using $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Thanks, Moos and Quasicoherent! With the hint, I am able to come up with an idea and found that I partly misunderstood the problem! Also, for Quasicoherent, I appreciate for nice information.

Comment: @MooS Could you please tell me how can I show that property? I can show it for basic open sets but I'm stuck in the general case

Comment: @EpsilonDelta could you articulate what you're looking for here with your bounty? This question is kind of a mess and could use some clarification, but the OP hasn't logged in on the site in more than a year.

Comment: @Kreiser. I'm just curious how we can prove the statement the OP states, i.e. we can view the local sections as fractions. În Dummit and Foote and othee books like Hartshorne, local sections are chosen to be locally constant while here it seems we can choose them globally constant. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Here we have an affine scheme, so an open set $U$ can be described explicitly as $U = \{P \in \operatorname{Spec}(R): P \supsetneq I\}$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$. Is this enough to clarify your question?

Comment: @WhatsUp. Not really. I'm aware of this. Really my question is the same as the OP's. I want this question to be answered: why can we view the sections on $U$ as described in the question above (i.e. globally constant instead of locally).

Comment: @EpsilonDelta What do you mean by globally constant? Do you mean that it is represented by a global fraction $\frac a b \in F$?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta If this is you question, then you might think like this: since $R$ is integral, there is the generic point $\eta \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$, corresponding to the prime ideal $0$ of $R$. It lies in any non-empty open set $U$. Hence any section of $\mathcal O(U)$ can be restricted to $\eta$, and the restriction map $\mathcal O(U) \rightarrow \mathcal O(\eta)$ is injective, because the closure of $\eta$ is the whole space. Hence $\mathcal O(U)$ can be embedded into $\mathcal O(\eta)$, which is nothing but $F = \operatorname{Frac} A$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. If you follow the definition of the structure sheaf in Hartsthorne, it are locally constant functions. Expand a bit on your last comment in an answer so I can award you the bounty!